# how to get data whose expired within 45 days..?

Tags: sql

HI all,

i have one sql table and field for that table is

```
id
name
expireydate
```

Now i want only those record which one is expired within 45 days or 30 days.

how can i do with sql query .?
I have not much more exp with sql .

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what database are you using? date/time manipulation functions tend not to be very portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using mysql then try [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

for 45 days

```
select * from `table` where DATEDIFF(now(),expireydate)<=45;
```

for 30 days

```
select * from `table` where DATEDIFF(now(),expireydate)<=30;
```

---

In oracle `-` will do the trick instead of datediff and `SYSDATE` instead of `now()`.[not sure]

---

In sql server DateDiff is quite different you have to provide unit in which difference to be taken out from 2 dates.

`DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)`

to get current date try one of this: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `GETDATE()` or `{fn NOW()}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE expireydate < "some formula calculating today+30 or 45 days"`.

Simple comparison will work there, the tricky part is to write this last bit concerning the date you want to compare to. It'll depend of your environment and how you stored the "expireydate" in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:-

```
 SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE (expireydate in days) < ((CURRENTDATE in days)+ 45)
```

Do not execute directly! Depending of your database, way of obtaining a date in days will be different. Go look at your database manual or please precise what is your database.